# Why Editing a GeoPackage table with ogr is very slow?

Tags: qgis, python, ogr, geopackage

I want to edit some fields in a GeoPackage [(download a.gpkg)](http://makobo.de/upload4forum/a.zip)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from osgeo import ogr
from time import clock

print ("Start",clock())
source = ogr.Open("c:/.../a.gpkg",update=True)
layer = source.GetLayerByName( "263c6845-e2c3-4eee-ae26-f0e9539f3c2bP" )
laydef = layer.GetLayerDefn()

i=0
feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
while feature:
    i=i+1
    # make some stuff
    # .....
    layer.SetFeature(feature)
    feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
source.Destroy()
print ("Finish",i,clock())
```

> ('Start', 3.4136520136791866e-07) ('Finish', 1612, 243.56666043106233)

It works, but it takes a long time (4 minutes for 1.600 records).

What is going wrong?

Comment: how big are your features? does it have indexes on? what "stuff" are you doing?

Comment: 4 minutes without stuff. The GeoPackage is a result from a DXF-convert. I have linked the GeoPackage above

Comment: Spatial index already existing

Comment: Does your code make a new transaction for each feature?

Comment: I do not know what happens internally. But the posted code is the complete code (which takes 4 minutes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make a minor but important change and make all edits to happen within one transaction instead of doing one transaction for each row. Transactions are rather expensive for SQLite and therefore also for GeoPackage. Making less but bigger transactions is faster. You can find some numbers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite.

A modified script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from osgeo import ogr
from time import clock

print ("Start",clock())
source = ogr.Open("a.gpkg",update=True)
layer = source.GetLayerByName( "263c6845-e2c3-4eee-ae26-f0e9539f3c2bP" )
laydef = layer.GetLayerDefn()
layer.StartTransaction()
i=0
feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
while feature:
    i=i+1
    # make some stuff
    # .....
    layer.SetFeature(feature)
    feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
layer.CommitTransaction()
source.Destroy()
print ("Finish",i,clock())
```

Compare the timings:

With one transaction

```
python run_a.py
('Start', 7.292488590901599e-07)
('Finish', 1612, 0.09405851784544883)
```

Original script without transaction:

```
python run_a.py
('Start', 7.292488590901599e-07)
('Finish', 1612, 15.54201567301648)
```

I have SSD disk which may explain why your original script is considerably faster for me (15.5 sec vs. 243.56 sec).

Comment: That looks good. This is exactly what I imagined. I searched for a transaction but found nothing.
The same problem occurs when using "-skipfailure" in OGR2OGR:
Will test it on Tuesday with the real data.

Comment: -skipfailures forces the size of a transaction into one row because in case of failure the whole transaction must be rolled back. If speed matters it is usually better to avoid -skipfailures and spend time for fixing the source data so that no failures will happen. GDAL transactions are documented in http://www.gdal.org/classOGRLayer.html#ac3cdf24212ec4719ade6065dcb63bb37.

Comment: +1 The explicit open/close transaction made a huge difference to my bulk inserts! (for some reason I thought OGR was already doing this. Ah well!)

Answer (score 4):

What is going on is that the features in the GeoPackage file are modified directly i.e. the code writes to the file when it is calling `layer.SetFeature(feature)` in the loop. What you should do is to create a copy of the layer to the memory, edit the features in the memory layer and copy the memory layer back to the GeoPackage file.

Test with the following code took about 4 seconds with the a.gpkg file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from osgeo import ogr
from time import clock

print ("Start",clock())
source = ogr.Open("c:/.../a.gpkg",update=False)
layer = source.GetLayerByName( "263c6845-e2c3-4eee-ae26-f0e9539f3c2bP" )
laydef = layer.GetLayerDefn()

driver_mem = ogr.GetDriverByName('MEMORY')
source_mem = driver_mem.CreateDataSource('memData')
#open the memory datasource with write access
tmp_mem = driver_mem.Open('memData',update=True)
#copy a layer to memory
layer_mem = source_mem.CopyLayer(layer,'263c6845-e2c3-4eee-ae26-f0e9539f3c2bP',['OVERWRITE=YES'])

i=0
for feature in layer_mem:
    i=i+1
    # make some stuff
    # ....
    layer.SetFeature(feature)

source.Destroy()

driver_dest = ogr.GetDriverByName('GPKG')
source_dest = driver_dest.CreateDataSource('c:/.../a.gpkg')
tmp_dest = driver_dest.Open('c:/.../a.gpkg',update=True)
layer_dest = source_dest.CopyLayer(layer_mem,'263c6845-e2c3-4eee-ae26-f0e9539f3c2bP',['OVERWRITE=YES'])

source_mem.Destroy()
source_dest.Destroy()
print ("Finish",i,clock())
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a good idea. I will test it on Tuesday under real conditions.
However, the statement "GeoPackage is the new shape format" is something wrong. With Shape I did not have to do any intermediate steps.

Comment: I agree that the GeoPackage file handling in various software needs to improve a lot but the Shape files that the statement probably refers to have 10 character size limitation for the table column names and also 2GB file size limitation that the GeoPackage files do not have and GeoPackage can also contain raster data.